# In a free-body diagram of motion on a banked road, is $N=mg\cos(\theta)?$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, free-body-diagram

[image]

For reference see the black highlighted angle in the picture.
If my assumption is correct, how can the equations formed further (including that formax velocity), since my book has derived the value of $N$ to be $mg/(\cos(\theta)-\mu_s\sin(\theta))$.

Forgive me as I don't have knowledge on how to write in the scientific form here.

Comment: The question is very close to being a Homework-type question, but still, your problem is with the concept.

The thing is, you are trying to resolve the vectors along their horizontal and vertical. But, resolution of vectors can be done in any way (with any number of axes).

Try resolving the components along any other axes (preferably perpendicular) and check. Only one possibility will present itself to you.

Comment: Can you please show me the process in detail?

Comment: Don't try to resolve N. Instead, try resolving mg into the other component parallel to the incline (by the way, yes,  N=mgcos(x)

Comment: So we have N=mgcos(x) and mg=Ncos(x). On comparing these two cos(x)=mg/N and also cos(x)=N/mg. But how can that be.

Comment: See, The job of the normal force is to prevent the block from sinking into the wedge. If you notice, the force trying to pull the box into the wedge is mgcos(x), so, N should be equal to mgcos(x).

Comment: N tries to adjust itself to the forces acting perpendicular to the point of contact. As such, N is dependent on situation. I'll ask you- will gravity adjust itself to eliminate the normal force, or will the normal force adjust? Thinking about this will lead you to the answer

Comment: It will always be Normal force that will adjust. But I am not getting what you want to explain. Do elaborate

Comment: If we get that $N=mgcos\theta$, then why there is need to equate two equations (relation in horizontal and vertical direction) to come up with the value of N.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you have forgotten the centrifugal force. The centrifugal force will act perpendicular to gravity in the direction of increasing incline

Comment: mv^2/R (sorry, no time for latex), can be divided into its components-along the plane and into it. Friction and gravity cancel out this force along the plane, and N takes care of mgcos(x) and the into the plane component of centrifugal force. Solve it, you'll get the expression for N

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106627/discussion-between-chatrapal-singh-rathore-and-krishna).